# How to check if an element of one list is another when they are in pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, list

Given a dataframe

```
d = {'col1': [['how', 'are', 'you'], ['im', 'fine', 'thanks'], ['you', 'know'], [np.nan]],
     'col2': [['tell', 'how', 'me', 'you'], ['who', 'cares'], ['know', 'this', 'padewan'], ['who', 'are', 'you']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to make a third column `col3` which is any element in the list in `col2` that is contained in the list in the corresponding row in the list in `col1`, otherwise `np.nan`.

It would have to take any elements that match.

In this case, then, `col3` would be:

```
           col1                      col2                           col3
0   ['how', 'are', 'you']      ['tell', 'how, 'me', 'you']        ['how', 'you']
1   ['im', 'fine', 'thanks']   ['who', 'cares']                   [np.nan] 
2   ['you', 'know']            ['know', 'this', 'padewan']        ['know']
3   [np.nan]                   ['who', 'are', 'you']              [np.nan]
```

I tried

```
df['col3'] = [c in l for c, l in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]
```

which doesn't work at all, so any ideas would be super helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another version:

```
df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda x: [*set(x['col1']).intersection(x['col2'])] or [np.nan], axis=1 )

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                 col1                   col2        col3
0     [how, are, you]   [tell, how, me, you]  [how, you]
1  [im, fine, thanks]           [who, cares]       [nan]
2         [you, know]  [know, this, padewan]      [know]
3               [nan]        [who, are, you]       [nan]
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
df['col3'] = [list(set(a).intersection(b)) for a, b in zip(df.col1, df.col2)]
```

Output:

```
                 col1                   col2        col3
0     [how, are, you]   [tell, how, me, you]  [you, how]
1  [im, fine, thanks]           [who, cares]          []
2         [you, know]  [know, this, padewan]      [know]
3               [nan]        [who, are, you]          []
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd write a separate function with help of `np.intersect1d` and apply:

```
def intersect_nan(a,b):
    ret = np.intersect1d(a,b) 
    return list(ret) if len(ret)>0 else [np.nan]

df['col3'] = [intersect_nan(a,b) for a,b in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]
```

Output:

```
                 col1                   col2        col3
0     [how, are, you]   [tell, how, me, you]  [how, you]
1  [im, fine, thanks]           [who, cares]       [nan]
2         [you, know]  [know, this, padewan]      [know]
3               [nan]        [who, are, you]       [nan]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
 d =  {'col1': [['how', 'are', 'you'], ['im', 'fine', 'thanks'], ['you', 'know'], [numpy.nan]],
                'col2': [['tell', 'how', 'me', 'you'], ['who', 'cares'], ['know', 'this', 'padewan'],
                      ['who', 'are', 'you']]}
        df = pandas.DataFrame(d)
        list_col3 = []
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            a_set= set(row['col1'])
            b_set= set(row['col2'])
            if len(a_set.intersection(b_set)) > 0:
                list_col3.append(list(a_set.intersection(b_set)))
            else:
                list_col3.append([numpy.nan])
        df['col3'] = list_col3
        print(df)
```

Output :

```
                 col1                   col2        col3
0     [how, are, you]   [tell, how, me, you]  [how, you]
1  [im, fine, thanks]           [who, cares]       [nan]
2         [you, know]  [know, this, padewan]      [know]
3               [nan]        [who, are, you]       [nan]
```

Comment: for this, u can avoid iterrows, as it will be slower than the other solutions provided